# Error when using make to create pg_strom extension for Postgresql: “make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.”

Tags: postgresql, makefile, centos, centos7

As the title says, we are following the build instructions for creating the pgstrom extension for Postgresql 10 (to allow us to use GPUs).

[This](http://heterodb.github.io/pg-strom/install/#pg-strom-installation) link gives us the following instructions, down in the 'Building the pgstrom' section:

```
$ cd pg-strom
$ make PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config
$ sudo make install PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config
```

We change directory to our pg_strom folder, but when we run the make command, we get the error seen in the title.

There's no makefile in the pg_strom folder, and ./configure gives us a file not found error. Autoconf doesn't work either, and cmake is not known.

We are installing on CentOS 7 (the install instructions we're using are for Red Hat/CentOS), and I'm not sure what we're missing. Since this is a basic step in the official documentation, I would have assumed that the makefile would have been available and ready to go?

We checked our CUDA installation (a troubleshooting tip found in the documentation), but it's in the place the pgstrom install is supposed to expect.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. We can't get past this step, and pg_strom and postgres need to have their configurations synced for things to work properly.

Comment: Can you see a `Makefile` in your current directory where you run `make`?

Comment: We had a bad rpm file that did not include the makefile. Used a clean install from github and works as expected. Will answer below and close out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Turns out the rpm file we installed from was missing the makefile. We installed from the github repository and everything worked as expected. I recommend heading there to anyone else that experiences this issue.